# better way to modify sudoers file

Tags: linux, sudo, sudoers

We used to run our application as a special user (say "suser") instead of root user. So we will give some permissions to this suser for running some commands without needing a password by adding this in the `/etc/sudoers` file.

I believe changing this file will require a reboot or log off. Correct me if I am wrong.

Which one is better changing directly /etc/sudoers file or adding a separate sudoers file in /etc/sudoers.d directory ? Is there any reason to avoid modifying /etc/sudoers file directly ?

During uninstall of my application, is removing the user (suser) alone enough?

Comment: Nope, log off is not required.

Comment: If you plan to distribute your application somehow, then you may prefer to use a separate file in /etc/sudo.d/. Also linux/unix traditionally has a decent pool of tools to edit text files in an unattended/automatic mode (just for example: sed, awk, perl) so practically it almost doesn't matter whether you keep the settings in a one central file or spread settings across a set of files. It's all about personal preferences and slight differences in conditions

Comment: @user3159253, Thanks for your info. Yes we are going to distribute our application. So I will consider adding permissions in a separate file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing /etc/sudoers file does not require a reboot or log off changes are reflected immediately once the file is saved.using the visudo command is the recommended way to update sudoers content, since it protects against many failure modes.

keeping changes in /etc/sudoers.d directory is a convenient way to add and remove permissions(application specific) instead of modifying the /etc/sudors file.